# Domain Name not working with Nginx (Python: Flask+Gunicorn+Nginx)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, domain-name

I have a Domain Name buy from Gandi, the relative DNS is set down,too. The domain name can access my website (use XAMPP).This shows that the current domain name is valid.

~ About my API project ~

The project path is "/home/API_AIcustomerservice"

The API url is "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5062"

The python file of API named "start_test.py"

I'm very sure Gunicorn and Flask is worked. (I can access the API url by IP address successfully)

I run Gunicorn by command "`gunicorn -c /home/API_AIcustomerservice/gconfig.py start_test:app`" with gconfig.py

[gconfig.py]

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import multiprocessing
debug = True
loglevel = 'debug'
bind = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5062'
pidfile = 'log/gunicorn.pid'
logfile = 'log/debug.log'
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_class = 'gevent'
```

About Nginx I edited the file: vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
        listen 81;
        root /home/API_AIcustomerservice;
        server_name domainName www.domainName;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header x-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5062/;
        }
        location ~ ^\/static\/.*$ {
            root /home/API_AIcustomerservice;
        }
}
```

After edited, I run `sudo service nginx restart`

~ Conclusion ~

`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5062` can be accessed (of course)

`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:81` can be accessed like Above (seems Nginx worked)

But `DomainName:81` or `www.DomainName:81` can't be accessed

Are there another setting I missed?
Thank you for taking the time. I thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: First of all, u may check access log of nginx to examine if the request has already reached nginx.

Comment: @Light.G After I access DomainName:81, I check the access.log & error.log in /var/log/nginx, there is no new record.

Comment: That means your request has not reached nginx yet.

Comment: So, Is there any problem with my settings? @Light.G

Answer (score 0):

Check your Domain DNS server and resolve ip

nginx config true

you can test resolve domain localy and test it again
definds dns in os hosts file, like:

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx DomainName

in windows:

```
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

in linux:

```
/etc/hosts
```